# PayPal- Payments Rest API

Tags: paypal-rest-sdk

I have used the **Create Payment(https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment)** RestAPI in my project.As per PayPal official documentation,the PayPal-v1/payments will be deprecated.
I have not found the similar RestAPI to achieve this in PayPal-Payments-v2 Documentation.
How to achieve the Create Payment operation(Rest API) using Payments-v2 in PayPal or is there any alternative to achieve the same operation.
Thank you.

I went through PayPal official documentation in order to find Create Payment operation in PayPal\Payments\v2.

Answer (score 0):

The current API is v2/checkout/orders. See the standard integration documentation, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/

v2/payments is for later post-checkout operations such as refunds

Comment: Thanks for the response.
But the Request and response payloads of Create payment(v1) and Order(v2) is different.

Comment: Indeed they are, v1/payments is obsolete.